# Lecture Notes or videos closely following Peskin & Schroeder QFT chapter 6 and chapter 7 (Radiative Correction)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education, perturbation-theory

I am looking for Lecture Notes or videos closely following Peskin & Schroeder QFT chapter 6 and chapter 7 (Radiative Correction). I will be glad if someone suggest that.